# LongPress in MapKit

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am bulding an app in Swift 3.

Everything seams to be working ok however when I longPress in the map it acts like if it was longpressed twice.
I don't know why...
i've made a print inside the longpress, to count the longpresses and every time I longpress (one time) it detects two long presses... why is this happening? Whats wrong with it?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

var numberOfLongPress : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 38.925560

    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = -9.229723

    let lanDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: lanDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)

    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, span: span)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longpress(gestureRecognizer:)))

    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.5

    map.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)

}

func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.map)

    let coordinate = map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.map)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = coordinate

    annotation.title = "My Place"



    map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    print("longpress activated")

    numberOfLongPress = numberOfLongPress + 1

    print(numberOfLongPress) //detect number of long presses

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selector is called on every state change, so you better check the state and do what you need to do on `.began` or `.ended`.

```
func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    guard gestureRecognizer.state == .began else { return }

    // add annotation
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Let print the state of `gestureRecognizer`, you'll see `.began` and `.ended`. So let check the state of `gestureRecognizer` before add an annotation.

```
func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == began {
        // do something here
    }
}
```